# inserting powershell variable into msiexec command

Tags: powershell, variables, command, windows-installer

What we have here is a the need for a quick script to pass a variable name to a command line. Easy but I'm stumped anyway.  I need to use msiexec /f to repair an msi in the C:\windows\installer directory.  The MSI, however, has a variable name.  I need to get the local name and then put that name and path into the script. It should then run msiexec /f with the correct path and name to the local MSI.  This could be a simple quote/format thing or maybe I'm barking at the wrong door entirely.  I'm relatively new at this.  Any ideas?

```
$localpackageName = 'localPackageName'

get-wmiobject -class win32_product -filter "name = 'smart ink'" | select-object localpackage -outvariable localPackageName

Invoke-Expression -command C:\windows\system32\MSIExec.exe /f $localPackageName
```

Comment: You should avoid win32_product, see my comment below for the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to trigger a repair of Smart Ink there are easier approaches. Msiexec allows you to [pass it the guid for the ProductId](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490936.aspx) instead of a path to an msi. All you need to do is get the guid which should remain the same for all installations of the same version of the software. An easy way to get the GUID from the registry instead of invoking Win32_Product is:

```
##Read in installed packages, check for a displayname, split the key to get the GUID
$prodId = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
 Where-Object {$_.GetValue('DisplayName') -match 'smart ink'} |
 Foreach-Object { $_.Name -split '\\'} | Select-Object -last 1
```

In my case this returns {5ABC49B5-D0DC-428D-A082-4AEFF6490F04} as the Smart Ink Product ID. You can then pass this to msiexec.

```
msiexec /fa $prodId
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
$localPackageName = 'localPackageName'
$command = 'C:\windows\system32\MSIExec.exe /f'

get-wmiobject -class win32_product -filter "name = 'smart ink'" | select-object localpackage -outvariable localPackageName

$packageName = $localPackageName.localpackage

$string = '{0} {1}' -f $command, $packageName
Invoke-Expression $string
```

Comment: Downvoted because win32_product should be avoided at all costs. It forces a consistency check on ALL registered MSI packages and automaticly does a repair which can reset custom settings (been there myself). Because of the re register of packages it's also very slow. You can verify this by checking the application eventlog after querying this class.